# Bohr effect in respiration

Tags: biochemistry, respiration

Would I be correct in saying that the Bohr effect is ONLY related to the concentration of [H+] in the tissues.

Obviously the concentration of carbon-dioxide can contribute to this concentration by producing protons (through carbonic anhydrase) but it isn't directly involved in the effect?

Answer (score 2):

> Would I be correct in saying that the Bohr effect is ONLY related to the concentration of [H+] in the tissues.

I would say no. Because oxygen binding affinity is inversely related to **both** [1]:

- high $[H^+]$ concentration **and**
- $CO_2$ increase (which is can be a consequence of the first)

$CO_2$ is involved in the Bohr effect:

> The biological significance of the negative influence of the carbon dioxide pressure on the oxygen binding of blood is obviously very big. [...] During the bloods movement through the body the oxygen-pressure will decrease to a relatively low value, whereas at the same time the carbon dioxide-pressure rises. This will greatly support the oxygen release from the blood, resulting in an improved efficiency in oxygen usage [2].

---

References:

1. Wikipedia contributors, "Bohr effect," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bohr_effect&oldid=618215597 (accessed August 4, 2014).
2. Chr. Bohr, K. Hasselbalch, and August Krogh. *Concerning a Biologically Important Relationship - The Influence of the Carbon Dioxide Content of Blood on its Oxygen Binding.* Available from http://www.udel.edu/chem/white/C342/Bohr%281904%29.html (accessed 04.08.2014)

Answer (score 1):

In a strict sense, I think you are correct that [H$^+$] contributes *directly* to the Bohr effect. A paper by [Perutz et al. (1980)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022283680800222) identified at least two amino acid residues in hemoglobin that account for the Bohr effect by interacting directly with H$^+$. CO$_2$ is not directly involved. Further, the Bohr effect (and the Root effect) are defined in terms of pH.

You and @Cornelius are correct that CO$_2$ contributes to the Bohr effect but speaking strictly it is a contributor and not the proximal cause. CO$_2$ dissolved in water produces H$_2$CO$_3$ which dissociates to release H$^+$, decreasing pH. But, lactic acid ([for example](http://www.biolbull.org/content/84/3/207.full.pdf)) can also contribute to the Bohr effect again through the release of H$^+$.

While CO$_2$ and lactic acid contribute to the Bohr effect through the release of H$^+$, the H$^+$ is the actual cause through interaction with amino acids in the hemoglobin.

1. Perutz, M.F., et al. 1980. Identification of residues contributing
   to the Bohr effect of human haemoglobin. J. Molecular Biology 138:
   649-668.
2. Root, R.W. and L. Irving. 1943. The effect of carbon dioxide and
   lactic acid on the oxygen-combining power of whole and hemolyzed
   blood of the marine fish *Tautoga onitis* (Linn.). Biological
   Bulletin 84: 207-212.